# weird string concat in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I got weird on string concat in jQuery as follow :

```
      var name = button.data('name')
      var emailName = button.data('email')
      var userName = button.data('username')
      var userStatus = button.data('active')
      var userId = button.data('id')
      alert(userId)
      var actionUpdate = "{{action('UserController@update', "+userId+")}}" 
      alert(actionUpdate)
```

and result/alert for userId is 28723050-71e9-11e7-a0a9-e9f620359699 (uuid as user id) but when I concated/joined, I got actionUpdate variable is {{action('UserController@update', "userId")}} instead of {{action('UserController@update', "28723050-71e9-11e7-a0a9-e9f620359699")}} as what I expected.

I tried to join those string and variable with concat or +=, but didn't get a result as expected.

Any alternatives and solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Double check that that is the exact concatenation that you are doing.  I'm not seeing a syntax error.  Actually it can't be exactly what you are doing, as you said the result has `"` in it, where as the example you gave would not include double quotes in the result

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried in JSfiddle and work well also, my purpose is make an update user in bootstrap modal with laravel, so I need this  userId as variable instead of "userId" as string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some odd reason, what you really want is

`{{action('UserController@update', "28723050-...9699")}}`

with single-quotes around the `UserController@update` and double-quotes around the `userId`, I think you need

```
  var userId = button.data('id')
  alert(userId)
  var actionUpdate = "{{action('UserController@update', \""+userId+"\")}}" 
  alert(actionUpdate)
```

(i.e., you need to add an escaped double-quote character on either side of the concatenation part.)

Comment: it works well as expected on https://jsfiddle.net/nprasetyo/2gnusjgt/, but still problem on my application, tried userId.toString(), but still no luck lol

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John, for your idea about "escaped char", this work as I expected now, I guess "{,{,},}" has special meaning in JS or Jquery, so I wrote this line as :

var actionUpdate = "{{action('UserController@update', '" + userId + "')}}"

hope it can be useful for who want to change form submit action to laravel controller.

Comment: I mean, prefixed with \ (backslash before {,}) but didn't show up above.